# Dixit variations to increase replay value?

Tags: house-rules, dixit

I recently got *Dixit*, and it's been a big hit with a couple groups of friends, however we're already finding it's replay value to be declining. I'm sure in a few months it would be very fun again (though never again as good as the first time, marveling at the beautiful artwork), but rather than wait it out I thought it might be nice to try some variations.

We played one game where each player had a second hand of the description cards from *Apples to Apples*, which we used instead of coming up with our own descriptors, and that worked pretty well. (We played that you kept 4 cards in that hand, and when you played one you could discard up to 2 others for new cards.) **Has anyone tried anything else to successfully vary the *Dixit* gameplay?**

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes! You simply have to fix rules about the sentence you want to use when it's your turn to play. For example: you must say a movie title, or lyrics from a song, or you can only make a grimace of some sort, or just a sound, and so on.

We've tried something else that completely changes the game: **first**, the other players give you a card of their choosing, and **then** you choose a title for your card. Note that it's still your card that must be guessed, but knowing what cards will be in the game, you can choose a sentence differently. This works well when all the players know all the cards and know exactly what words they have to use when playing a given card.

Answer (score 3):

We had three variants:

1. for a more casual play, you can discard cards and draw replacements whenever you want. this lifts some of the mental blocks.
2. A player must play the same clue twice in a row, so he has to choose his clue wisely.
3. As a catch-up mechanic - the player with the least points gets to play two cards.

Answer (score 2):

There are also a few expansions out there.  Increasing the pool of images helps.

Comment: Can you expand on this answer, perhaps with some descriptions of, or links to, the expansions? Or your own experiences with them?

Answer (score 1):

In some cases it helps to force a theme for clues. For example, you must use song lyrics as a clue, or only movie quotes. These, sadly, depend on knowledge of particular medium in reference. But since we know each other, we tend to choose a medium that's suitable for everyone.

Comment: I play dixit a lot on http://www.boiteajeux.net/  Where several games are themed or have rules for clues such as "start with the letter B" or "5 letter words".  In normal dixit where you tell a player then can say/do anything I find some players freeze.  When you put a rule on clue giving I find the creativity comes out much more and you will find clue giving varied again.